# RegEx expression to split a string on comma with a condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm very new to RegEx expressions and the problem is that I want to split a string with some conditions using RegEx. Let's say I want to split by comma, but if it's not followed by some certain things. The following example shows everything:

```
str = "a , b=10 , c=add(3,b) , d"
certainThings = ["add" , "sub"]
```

output of `str.split(',')` which splits only by comma is: `["a" , "b=10" , "c=add(3" , "b)" , "d"]`.

But I don't want to split on the 3rd comma as it's followed by one of the elements of the `certainThings` array.

The expected output is: `["a" , "b=10" , "c=add(3,b)" , "d"]`.

A possible solution might be to split by comma and concatenate two elements if the prior contains one elements of the `certainThings` array. But I think there should be a better way of doing this by RegEx expressions.

Comment: If you really have those empty spaces before and after the comma, as it looks on your sample, you can do `str.split(' , ')` split by comma followed and led by empty space

Comment: The third comma is not followed by "add" or "sub". Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only ever would have to worry about excluding commas inside singly-nested parentheses, we can try splitting on the following regex pattern:

```
\s*,\s*(?![^(]*\))
```

This says to split on comma, surrounded on both sides by optional whitespace, so long as we *can't* look forward and encounter a closing `)` parenthesis without *also* first seeing an opening `(` one.  This logic rules out the comma inside `c=add(3,b)`, because that particular comma hits a `)` first without seeing the opening one `(`.

```js
var str = "a , b=10 , c=add(3,b) , d"
parts = str.split(/\s*,\s*(?![^(]*\))/);
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's actually a good idea to exclude commas between parentheses and it totally works, but still doesn't check whether the function name which comes before parentheses (`add` in the abovementioned example) exists in the `certainThings` array or not.
So, is it also possible to put this test in our RegEx?

Comment: @BeHFaR This is where regex needs to stop.  If you have this type of requirement, you should write a parser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting on comma you could also select everything that is not a comma:

```js
const str = "a , b=10 , c=add(3,b) , d";
const regex = /(?:\([^)]*\)|[^,])+/g;

console.log(
  str.match(regex).map(str => str.trim())
);
```

[image: regex diagram]